# How to install gcc 11.2.0 on macOS Big Sur with the Apple M1 processor

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

How do I install the latest version of GCC on my macOS Big Sur. I am using Visual Studio Code, version 1.60 and I want to run C++ programs using it. I tried using homebrew to install GCC but it kept on giving me errors.

E.g.: When I typed in the path as /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/bin

Result: zsh: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/bin

What is wrong with the permission? How will I make it allow.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work. But thanks for trying to help. I came to the conclusion that gcc is not suitable in the mac world i.e mac IDE. I think the clang compiler is doing better in my case.  So I installed Xcode on my mac with supports all the extensions of C++ and is suitable for my mac because it uses clang compiler. When I looked in  /usr/local/bin, my terminal gave this output --> zsh: no matches found: /usr/local/bin/g++*. Anyways there were random problems hitting me but now I am working with Xcode which is pretty smooth. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/bin` is a directory, so you can't run that.

Secondly, **homebrew** generally makes symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` for everything it installs, so you should add that to your PATH, e.g.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then you need to look in `/usr/local/bin` to see what program name you need, e.g.

```
ls /usr/local/bin/gcc*
```

and if you see `gcc-11` in there, you then need to compile with:

```
gcc-11 program.c
```

Note you will need to look for `g++*` if you actually mean C++ rather than C.